# Issue with AWS Elastic Load Balancing sticky sessions - subdomains are being served from different servers?

Tags: session, amazon-web-services, load-balancing, subdomain

I'm quite new to load balancing and I'm having some problems with getting Amazon's Elastic Load Balancer to play nice with subdomains.

I have two EC2 servers behind my load balancer.  When I go to *mydomain.com* and *www.mydomain.com*, the two urls are served from different EC2 servers.  I need both *www.mydomain.com* and *mydomain.com* to be served from the same server so that sessions work properly.

I have the load balancer "stickyness" set to LBCookieStickinessPolicy like so:

[image]

And my two EC2 instances are both "In Service" behind my load balancer:

[image]

I don't know if it's useful for troubleshooting, but my apache configuration looks like:

[image]

When I view the sessions in Firebug, I see the following...

For mydomain.com:

[image]

For www.mydomain.com (notice the additional "www.")

[image]

I'm not sure why, but there are actually two AWSELB cookies set when viewing the cookies for www.mydomain.com.

I'm using the Zend Framework, and I'm setting my cookie_domain like so:

```
Zend_Session::start(array('cookie_domain' => '.mydomain.com'));
```

This has worked fine in the past before moving the site to the two load balanced EC2 servers.  Our site uses a few subdomains, such as api.mydomain.com and my.mydomain.com, which made the cookie_domain important.  And, granted, this might be OK.  It's quite possible that once we get the load balancer session "sticky" to work properly between subdomains, session variables will work as expected (hopefully!).

Any ideas why our site is being served from different servers when the "www." is added to the domain name?

Thanks!

Comment: I'd like to comment that I worked around my issue by using "Application-Controlled Session Stickiness" (http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/US_EnableStickySessionsAppCookies.html).  I'd still love to hear any answers to my original question.

Answer (score 4):

Cookies are set by domain, including the subdomain part. A www.example.com cookie cannot be read when you go to http://example.com , so the ELB sets a new cookie.

To deal with this issue, you can set Apache up to 301 redirect all incoming requests to one canonical domain. That is, either all http://example.com/* gets redirected to http://www.example.com/*, or vice versa. Then you only have to deal with cookies on the canonical domain, and your session stickiness will work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

please see the following link then you understand it. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/US_StickySessions.html

Answer (score 0):

One way you could manage sessions is to utilize a shared session storage. Instead of using the filesystem for storing session data (the default for PHP, for example), set up something like ElastiCache (memcached) or the DB to handle storing of session data. Then your application won't care what server it's on, it has one central store of session data to pull from.

An article I found interesting around the basics of this concept is here: http://shlomoswidler.com/2010/04/elastic-load-balancing-with-sticky-sessions.html